# Select Several Rows of Data Using Condition in One Column and Each Row

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help please. I am trying to import data into my current workbook from the "CA-2016" workbook. In my current workbook I want to fill only one cell. In the "CA-2016" workbook, the data is listed by day. The date is in the "J" column starting from "J7", and the sum of the data that I want are in the "I" (0,-1) and "E" column (0,-4). However I want to sum this data by the month. So below I have the condition where the month "MMM" has to match. In my current sheet, the date is written as 11/01/2016, to indicate that I want to sum from the first of the month. I then want to cycle through the "CA-2016" workbook by comparing "MMM" and sum the columns if this is true. The code I have below does not run. Is there something that I can do better? I was thinking that I need to run it through a For Loop, but I have that commented out at the moment. I am also getting a compile error at rcell9 in the line: `...=rcell9 Then`

```
Sub DataImport()
    Dim rcell5, rcell6, rcell7, rcell8, rcell9 As Long
    rcell5 = Range("F2").Value
    rcell9 = Range("F2").Value
    Workbooks.Open "\\Inventory\CA-2016.xlsx"
    Worksheets("Total Year").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("J7").Select
    rcell8 = 0

    'For i = 1 To 31
        Do While rcell5 <> Selection.Value
            If Selection.Value = rcell5 And Selection.Value("MMM") = rcell9("MMM") Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
            Else
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
        Loop
        rcell5 = Selection.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        rcell6 = Selection.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Select
        rcell7 = Selection.Value
        rcell8 = rcell6 + rcell7 + rcell8
    'Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing `Selection.Value("MMM") = rcell9("MMM")` into `Format(Selection.Value, "MMM") = Format(rcell9.Value, "MMM")`. This should fix the current error and get you further.

Comment: ^^ or use `Month(Selection.Value)` and `Month(rcell9)`.

Comment: @A.S.H  - P.S. `rcell9.Value` in your comment should be just `rcell9` - it's defined as a `Long`.  (`rcell5`, etc are defined as `Variant`, but that's another story.)

Comment: Ignore my comment about the meaninglessnessicity of the test - I didn't notice that `rcell5` was being redefined later.

Comment: @YowE3K you are right. Didnt realize that rcell9 was actually a long, just interpreted its name (too lazy) .

Comment: @A.S.H - I must admit that every time I see a variable with the word `cell` contained within the name, I automatically think that it is a `Range` variable.  I struggled to realise that it was a `Long` in this code.

Comment: @YowE3K and here you got the `r` prefix in bonus....

Comment: Your `If Selection.Value = rcell5 And ...` statement will never evaluate to `True` because you are only executing it within a `Do While rcell5 <> Selection.Value`.

Comment: I am now getting a type mismatch in the line `If Selection.Value = rcell5 And Month(Selection.Value) = Month(rcell9) Then`

Comment: @YowE3K what do I need to do differently? I am really a novice.

Comment: (a) Do you have a valid date in cell F2 of your original sheet, and in cell J7 of `Workbooks("CA-2016.xlsx").Worksheets("Total Year")`?  I dummied up a situation that should be equivalent to that and it ran OK for me.  (b) Have you tried to uncomment your loop?  If so, you will need to first fix up your use of `Select`, `Selection` and `ActiveCell` (at the end of each loop your current `Selection` will be in column E !).  (c) It might be best if you posted an image of your `Total Year` worksheet, so that we can try and imagine what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am not sure how to post an image, I tried a few things but I may not have the rights yet. I have made a few changes and I'm getting closer. The update code is below, across a few comments. I am getting a Type Mismatch at the `If` statement though `Sub DataImport()
Dim rcell5, rcell6, rcell7, rcell8 As Long
rcell5 = Range("F2").Value
rcell9 = Range("F2").Value 
Workbooks.Open "\\Inventory\CA-2016.xlsx"
Worksheets("Total Year").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("J7").Select
rcell8 = 0`

Comment: `For i = 1 To 31
Do While Selection.Value <> recell5
If Selection.Value = rcell5 And Month(Selection.Value) = Month(rcell9) Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
Else: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
Loop
rcell5 = Selection.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
rcell6 = Selection.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Select
rcell7 = Selection.Value
rcell8 = rcell6 + rcell7 + rcell8
Next i

Workbooks("DataImport.xlsm").Activate
Range("H20").Select
ActiveCell.Value = rcell8
Workbooks("CA-2016.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub`